# Easy way to set font color in javascript onClick?

Tags: javascript, html, web

Question: So let's say I have some basic code

```
    <a name = "sec">this is a test</a>
```

I want a javascript function to on click of a link to change that to

So user clicks:
         link!

And the JS kicks in to change the 1st html to:

```
    <font color = "green"><a name = "sec">this is a test</a></font>
```

Is it possible to do this in JS?

Comment: Don't mean to push a library, but have you checked out jQuery? It makes this kind of stuff really easy. But if this is a one-off case, I'm sure it's also easy to do it in pure js.

Comment: oh... why would you use a font element.  Just use the style attribute.

Comment: <FONT> has been deprecated, use CSS instead.

Comment: I would but im using a ruby to generate html files thats why i need to do it with JS

Comment: @facebook-1389780026 — Use CSS instead of `<font>` not instead of JS

Answer (score 8):

You can set the element's color with JS as a simple solution. You should also give the element a valid href attribute that nullifies the default click behavior.

```
<a name="sec" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="this.style.color='green';">
  this is a test
</a>
```

Comment: Setting a property of an element's style object is not CSS. CSS is a way of applying styles to elements, it is completely separate from the elements themselves.

Comment: OK, my mistake, I edited my phrasing. Obviously an "ideal" solution would be to call a named javascript function to apply the style, or define the style to a class with CSS and use jQuery to add the class on the click, but if the user is generating html from another application all that overhead could be unnecessary in this narrow instance.

Comment: I think calling it inline style is  most common

Answer (score 2):

Try something along the lines of

```
<a href="#" onclick="this.style.color='green'; return false;">link</a>
```

And you should not use `<font>` tag for setting text attributes, this is considered bad practice in today’s HTML (be it XHTML or HTML5).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work: (Psudeo Code)

```
<a id="sec" onClick="makeGreen()">this is a test</a>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

function makeGreen() {
     document.getElementById('sec').style.color('green');
};

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Realistically, you should keep your semantics and your style separate. As other users have suggested, use a css class instead of modifying styles directly. This is fairly easy to do, as shown by this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rDmYd/)

```
<a href="#" id="my-link">This is a test</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var el = document.getElementById('my-link');
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.className = 'clicked-class';
  });
</script>
```

And of course in your CSS you would define some sort of rule:

```
.clicked-class {
  color: green;
}
```

This could be made even simpler with a javascript library of your choice, but hopefully should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(element).on("click",function() {$(this).css({'color', 'blue'});
```